# SilverStripe db select multiple keys match

Tags: php, silverstripe

How can you select rows from a db table based on multiple "identifiers"?

**Single key match**

```
$id = 42;
DataObject::get('Foo')->where("ID = '$id'");
```

**Multiple keys match**

```
$id = array(42, 43, 44);
DataObject::get('Foo')->where( ??? );
```

In the second case it should return a list of rows that have an ID 42, 43 or 44.

Comment: Not familiar with SilverStripe, but maybe the `IN` operator of SQL nudges you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SilverStripe ORM knows how to build `where in` queries:

```
$ids = array(42, 43, 44);
$items = Foo::get()->byIDs($ids);
```

For any other sets you should use `DataList::filter()` method;

```
$products = Product::get()->filter('Category', array('shirts', 'shoes'));
```

Comment: Great to know. Any easy way to supply a DataList like `$ids = Bar::get()->column("TheIDs");` instead of an array?

Comment: Then it looks like Foo and Bar are related. Probably it is better to use has_many relation?

Comment: You're right, I set a `has_many` relationship. I should be able to loop through the foreign table (Foo) on the front-end right?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$id = implode(',', array(42, 43, 44));

$items = DataObject::get('Foo')->where("ID IN ($id)");
```